# GetStream API Error: QueryUsers failed with error "Missing request payload"

Tags: java, jwt, getstream-io

I tried to use https://getstream.io/chat/docs_rest/#query-users

`GET https://....stream-io-api.com/users?api_key=...`

but I get the following error when I try to query users:

```
    "code": 4,
    "message": "QueryUsers failed with error: \"QueryUsers failed with error: \"QueryUsers failed with error: \"QueryUsers failed with error: \"QueryUsers failed with error: \"QueryUsers failed with error: \"QueryUsers failed with error: \"Missing request payload\"\"\"\"\"\"\"",
    "StatusCode": 400,
    "duration": "0.00ms",
    "more_info": "https://getstream.io/chat/docs/api_errors_response"
}
```

Can anyone help me how to add request payload at this API?

Thanks!

Comment: I think getstream should update rest api document for query users with `payload` param.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in OP's comment, their documentation seems to be missing important information.  You must wrap the query parameters in a `payload` query parameter.  For example, to search for users with id "1" or "2", calling from your backend (assuming `us-east-1` region):

Unencoded:

```
GET https://chat-us-east-1.stream-io-api.com/users?api_key=YOUR_APP_ID&payload={"filter_conditions":{"id":{"$in":["1", "2"]}}}
```

Encoded:

```
https://chat-us-east-1.stream-io-api.com/users?api_key=YOUR_APP_ID&payload=%7B%22filter_conditions%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%7B%22%24in%22%3A%5B%221%22%2C%20%222%22%5D%7D%7D%7D
```

Also ensure you have the `Stream-Auth-Type` and `Authorization` set appropriately per their documentation here: https://getstream.io/chat/docs_rest/#authentication